# Is it ok to use the super keyword as a method name?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, compatibility, keyword, super

I see that *most* frameworks do not use the keyword `super` on their object, instead they use something like `_super`

I understand that it's a **keyword** but is it safe & acceptable to use it as a method name like this

```
var Class = function() {
   this.super = function(){};
};


var instance = new Class()
instance.super()
```

It works fine in Chrome with `"use strict"` mode on.

Side note, I know that coffeescript "escapes" it like `this["super"]`, surely their must be a real reason for that.

Comment: In ECMAScript 5, all keywords can be used as property identifiers. Old browsers will fail, so if you need to support old ones, you'd need to use the `["super"]` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5, all keywords can be used as property identifiers. Old browsers will fail, so if you need to support old ones, you'd need to use the `["super"]` syntax.

Comment: Cheers Cookie Monster ;)